# Force use of browser's right click menu instead on CKEditor's ContextMenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, ckeditor

I need to add contextmenu due to various table plugins (i need contextmenu), but I want to use the default browser right click due to spell checking / suggestions.

I am playing with the "onShow" of contextMenu but I dont know how to call the default browser right click menu.

Is this even possible?

Comment: When you keep `command` or `Ctrl`, then native context menu is open. Or do you need to change this behaviour to use native context menu by default?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use native context menu, please simply use the combination of `Ctrl+Right-Click`. Provided that https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-browserContextMenuOnCtrl isn't set to `false`  (default value is `true`) it should work out of the box.